# 'init' is unavailable:use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type

Tags: ios, swift3

here is an error:

```
'init' is unavailable:use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.
```

here is my code:

```
var inputSignal:[Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 512)

let xAsComplex = UnsafePointer<DSPComplex>( inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress } )//error here
```

why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using the idiom `.withUnsafeBufferPointer { $0.baseAddress }` to take an address of Swift `Array` is not recommended. The address taken from that idiom is not guaranteed to be valid outside the closure.

So, you can write something like this:

```
inputSignal.withUnsafeBufferPointer {buffer in
    buffer.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: inputSignal.count / (MemoryLayout<DSPComplex>.size/MemoryLayout<Float>.size)) {xAsComplex in
        //`xAsComlex` is guaranteed to be valid only in this closure.
        //...
    }
}
```

If you need to use stable pointers, you may need to manage them as actual pointers.

```
let inputSignalCount = 512
let inputSignal = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: inputSignalCount)
inputSignal.initialize(to: 0.0, count: inputSignalCount)

//...

inputSignal.withMemoryRebound(to: DSPComplex.self, capacity: inputSignalCount / (MemoryLayout<DSPComplex>.size/MemoryLayout<Float>.size)) {xAsComplex in
    //`xAsComlex` is guaranteed to be valid only in this closure.
    //...
}

//...

//Later when `inputSignal` is not needed any more...
inputSignal.deinitialize(count: inputSignalCount)
inputSignal.deallocate(capacity: inputSignalCount)
```